# can't change isotope filtering from end with on start with

Tags: javascript, filter, filtering, jquery-isotope

on the main page of [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co) exist demo with filtering by name ends with, but i need filtering by name starts with , it's will be pretty usefull for filter by alphabet. Please help me, i'm noob in javascript.

this demo:

```
$container.isotope({ filter: function() {
  var name = $(this).find('.name').text();
  return name.match( /ium$/ );
} })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "ends with" part comes from the regex you use. The "$" at the end of itis the end-of-string character, and makes sure that the regex only matches if this string is found at the end of your name string.

For starts with, try something like:

```
return name.match( /^ium/ );
```

"^" is the opposite of "$" in that it matches the beginning of the string